# Can I sort Global Environment by type numeric and extract all into one CSV? Or create a data table in from 500+ values in each column directly in R?

Tags: r, data.table, export-to-csv, data-wrangling

So I've saved over 500 numeric values as dataframes in R. I now need to make a 3-column data table with these values.

Can I sort the values in the Global Environment as numeric and then extract them into one CSV?

Or perhaps it would be easier to just create the data table in R itself, however, I would rather avoid listing each variable's name out for the function: write.csv(rbind( ), file = "test.csv", row.names = T)

My data is as follows and I only need the numeric values, not the data tables.

```
> str(as.list(.GlobalEnv))
List of 1174
 $ May26RMRA8comp   :Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame': 6 obs. of  6 variables:
  ..$ DateTime   : chr [1:6] "2020/05/26 16:58:00" "2020/05/26 17:03:00" "2020/05/26 17:18:00" "2020/05/26 17:13:00" ...
  ..$ kcal_hr_M_8: num [1:6] 0.254 0.214 0.231 0.251 0.251 ...
  ..$ VO2_M_8    : num [1:6] 0.884 0.749 0.79 0.856 0.872 ...
  ..$ VCO2_M_8   : num [1:6] 0.695 0.583 0.706 0.766 0.711 ...
  ..$ Sum_6period: num [1:6] 1.46 1.5 1.52 1.53 1.54 ...
  ..$ ..I        : int [1:6] 45 46 49 48 47 50
  ..- attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr> 
 $ August24RMRA5comp:Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame': 6 obs. of  6 variables:
  ..$ DateTime   : chr [1:6] "2020/08/24 17:27:00" "2020/08/24 17:32:00" "2020/08/24 17:37:00" "2020/08/24 17:42:00" ...
  ..$ kcal_hr_M_5: num [1:6] 0.275 0.263 0.269 0.256 0.27 ...
  ..$ VO2_M_5    : num [1:6] 0.958 0.915 0.933 0.887 0.935 ...
  ..$ VCO2_M_5   : num [1:6] 0.774 0.734 0.76 0.721 0.765 ...
  ..$ Sum_6period: num [1:6] 1.61 1.61 1.67 1.77 1.83 ...
  ..$ ..I        : int [1:6] 56 57 58 59 60 61
  ..- attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr> 
 $ June11RMRA2comp  :Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame': 6 obs. of  6 variables:
  ..$ DateTime   : chr [1:6] "2020/06/11 23:37:00" "2020/06/11 23:42:00" "2020/06/11 23:47:00" "2020/06/11 23:52:00" ...
  ..$ kcal_hr_M_2: num [1:6] 0.283 0.257 0.272 0.26 0.249 ...
  ..$ VO2_M_2    : num [1:6] 1.018 0.92 0.969 0.938 0.916 ...
  ..$ VCO2_M_2   : num [1:6] 0.675 0.613 0.675 0.646 0.633 ...
  ..$ Sum_6period: num [1:6] 1.59 1.6 1.7 1.73 1.76 ...
  ..$ ..I        : int [1:6] 124 125 126 127 128 129
  ..- attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr> 
 $ August12MassA1   : num 15.4
 $ August12MassA2   : num 0
 $ August12MassA3   : num 20.9
 $ FinalRMJune7A1   : num 0.211
 $ August12MassA4   : num 15.5
 $ June1RMRA3comp   :Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame': 6 obs. of  6 variables:
  ..$ DateTime   : chr [1:6] "2020/06/02 07:15:00" "2020/06/02 07:30:00" "2020/06/02 07:25:00" "2020/06/02 07:20:00" ...
  ..$ kcal_hr_M_3: num [1:6] 0.258 0.222 0.252 0.253 0.24 ...
  ..$ VO2_M_3    : num [1:6] 0.9 0.774 0.876 0.883 0.843 ...
  ..$ VCO2_M_3   : num [1:6] 0.703 0.609 0.713 0.694 0.639 ...
  ..$ Sum_6period: num [1:6] 1.49 1.49 1.5 1.5 1.51 ...
  ..$ ..I        : int [1:6] 225 228 227 226 229 230
  ..- attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr> 
 $ FinalRMJune7A2   : num 0.215
 $ August12MassA5   : num 15.1
 $ FinalRMJune7A3   : num 0.243
 $ August12MassA6   : num 21.8
 $ FinalRMJune7A4   : num 0.296
 $ August12MassA7   : num 0
 $ FinalRMJune7A5   : num 0.224
 $ August12MassA8   : num 17.2
 $ FinalRMJune7A6   : num 0.161
 $ FinalRMJune7A7   : num 0.237
 $ RMRVCO2May26A1   : num -0.00763
 $ FinalRMJune7A8   : num 0.188
 $ RMRVCO2May26A2   : num 0.699
 $ RMRVCO2May26A3   : num 0.608
 $ August19RMRA4comp:Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame': 6 obs. of  6 variables:
  ..$ DateTime   : chr [1:6] "2020/08/20 09:44:00" "2020/08/20 09:49:00" "2020/08/20 09:59:00" "2020/08/20 09:54:00" ...
  ..$ kcal_hr_M_4: num [1:6] 0.288 0.307 0.301 0.312 0.28 ...
  ..$ VO2_M_4    : num [1:6] 0.992 1.052 1.049 1.065 0.97 ...
  ..$ VCO2_M_4   : num [1:6] 0.827 0.9 0.862 0.889 0.804 ...
  ..$ Sum_6period: num [1:6] 1.76 1.79 1.8 1.8 1.8 ...
  ..$ ..I        : int [1:6] 236 237 239 238 240 241
  ..- attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr> 
 $ RMRVCO2May26A4   : num 0.59
 $ RMRVCO2May26A5   : num 0.724
 $ RMRVCO2May26A6   : num 0.71
 $ RMRVCO2June1A1   : num 0.531
 $ RMRVCO2May26A7   : num 0.702
 $ July7RMRA7comp   :Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame': 6 obs. of  6 variables:
  ..$ DateTime   : chr [1:6] "2020/07/08 08:28:00" "2020/07/08 08:33:00" "2020/07/08 08:43:00" "2020/07/08 08:38:00" ...
  ..$ kcal_hr_M_7: num [1:6] 0.275 0.189 0.178 0.239 0.141 ...
  ..$ VO2_M_7    : num [1:6] 0.928 0.64 0.605 0.813 0.489 ...
  ..$ VCO2_M_7   : num [1:6] 0.873 0.604 0.556 0.752 0.464 ...
  ..$ Sum_6period: num [1:6] 1.29 1.32 1.38 1.39 1.46 ...
  ..$ ..I        : int [1:6] 218 219 221 220 222 223
  ..- attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr> 
 $ RMRVCO2June1A2   : num 0.524
 $ RMRVCO2May26A8   : num 0.701
 $ RMRVCO2June1A3   : num 0.678
 $ FinalRMJuly27A1  : num 0.258
 $ RMRVCO2June1A4   : num 0.578
 $ FinalRMJuly27A2  : num 0.219
 $ RMRVCO2June1A5   : num 0.693
 $ FinalRMJuly27A3  : num 0.204
 $ RMRVCO2June1A6   : num 0.712
 $ FinalRMJuly27A4  : num 0.185
 $ RMRVCO2June1A7   : num 0.561
 $ FinalRMJuly27A5  : num 0.321
 $ RMRVCO2June1A8   : num 0.605
 $ FinalRMJuly27A6  : num 0.27
 $ RMRVCO2June16A1  : num 0.578
 $ FinalRMJuly27A7  : num 0.202
 $ RMRVCO2June16A2  : num 0.437
 $ FinalRMJuly27A8  : num 0.229
 $ RMRVCO2June16A3  : num 0.801
 $ June7RMRA1       :Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame': 286 obs. of  6 variables:
  ..$ DateTime   : chr [1:286] "2020/07/07 10:05:00" "2020/07/07 10:50:00" "2020/07/07 10:55:00" "2020/07/07 12:00:00" ...
  ..$ kcal_hr_M_1: num [1:286] 0.216 0.227 0.198 0.257 0.232 ...
  ..$ VO2_M_1    : num [1:286] 0.746 0.776 0.679 0.869 0.792 ...
  ..$ VCO2_M_1   : num [1:286] 0.653 0.685 0.597 0.814 0.724 ...
  ..$ Sum_6period: num [1:286] 1.25 1.26 1.26 1.27 1.27 ...
  ..$ ..I        : int [1:286] 254 263 264 277 262 253 269 265 266 268 ...
  ..- attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr> 
  ..- attr(*, "index")= int(0) 
  .. ..- attr(*, "__..I")= int [1:286] 174 168 164 153 150 156 158 148 136 146 ...
 $ RMRVCO2June16A4  : num 0.726
 $ June7RMRA2       :Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame': 286 obs. of  6 variables:
  ..$ DateTime   : chr [1:286] "2020/07/07 10:55:00" "2020/07/07 11:10:00" "2020/07/07 10:50:00" "2020/07/07 11:00:00" ...
  ..$ kcal_hr_M_2: num [1:286] 0.211 0.202 0.235 0.211 0.195 ...
  ..$ VO2_M_2    : num [1:286] 0.719 0.695 0.807 0.723 0.677 ...
  ..$ VCO2_M_2   : num [1:286] 0.638 0.611 0.702 0.628 0.589 ...
  ..$ Sum_6period: num [1:286] 1.27 1.28 1.29 1.29 1.29 ...
  ..$ ..I        : int [1:286] 264 267 263 265 268 266 269 273 262 270 ...
  ..- attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr> 
  ..- attr(*, "index")= int(0) 
  .. ..- attr(*, "__..I")= int [1:286] 130 128 133 132 127 125 124 118 90 79 ...
 $ RMRVCO2June16A5  : num 0.864
 $ June7RMRA3       :Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame': 286 obs. of  6 variables:
  ..$ DateTime   : chr [1:286] "2020/07/07 12:05:00" "2020/07/07 12:15:00" "2020/07/07 12:10:00" "2020/07/07 11:25:00" ...
  ..$ kcal_hr_M_3: num [1:286] 0.237 0.24 0.245 0.247 0.263 ...
  ..$ VO2_M_3    : num [1:286] 0.826 0.837 0.86 0.859 0.917 ...
  ..$ VCO2_M_3   : num [1:286] 0.66 0.665 0.659 0.677 0.718 ...
  ..$ Sum_6period: num [1:286] 1.44 1.44 1.46 1.47 1.47 ...
  ..$ ..I        : int [1:286] 278 280 279 270 269 277 268 271 276 273 ...
  ..- attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr> 
  ..- attr(*, "index")= int(0) 
  .. ..- attr(*, "__..I")= int [1:286] 160 167 186 207 218 217 206 185 149 129 ...
 $ RMRVCO2June16A6  : num 0.569
 $ June7RMRA4       :Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame': 286 obs. of  6 variables:
  ..$ DateTime   : chr [1:286] "2020/07/07 11:40:00" "2020/07/07 11:45:00" "2020/07/07 11:35:00" "2020/07/07 11:05:00" ...
  ..$ kcal_hr_M_4: num [1:286] 0.3 0.312 0.305 0.293 0.287 ...
  ..$ VO2_M_4    : num [1:286] 1.06 1.09 1.07 1.03 1.02 ...
  ..$ VCO2_M_4   : num [1:286] 0.812 0.845 0.835 0.785 0.813 ...
  ..$ Sum_6period: num [1:286] 1.76 1.77 1.78 1.79 1.79 ...
  ..$ ..I        : int [1:286] 273 274 272 266 271 268 270 269 267 276 ...
  ..- attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr> 
  ..- attr(*, "index")= int(0) 
  .. ..- attr(*, "__..I")= int [1:286] 253 249 239 220 189 178 154 131 122 119 ...
 $ RMRVCO2June16A7  : num 0.578
 $ June7RMRA5       :Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame': 286 obs. of  6 variables:
  ..$ DateTime   : chr [1:286] "2020/07/07 10:50:00" "2020/07/07 10:55:00" "2020/07/07 10:45:00" "2020/07/07 11:00:00" ...
  ..$ kcal_hr_M_5: num [1:286] 0.234 0.231 0.232 0.216 0.201 ...
  ..$ VO2_M_5    : num [1:286] 0.796 0.786 0.783 0.726 0.675 ...
  ..$ VCO2_M_5   : num [1:286] 0.736 0.726 0.742 0.697 0.65 ...
  ..$ Sum_6period: num [1:286] 1.33 1.33 1.34 1.35 1.36 ...
  ..$ ..I        : int [1:286] 263 264 262 265 266 261 280 267 278 260 ...
  ..- attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr> 
  ..- attr(*, "index")= int(0) 
  .. ..- attr(*, "__..I")= int [1:286] 189 167 139 132 119 102 79 72 68 43 ...
 $ RMRVCO2June16A8  : num 0.678
 $ June7RMRA6       :Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame': 286 obs. of  6 variables:
  ..$ DateTime   : chr [1:286] "2020/07/07 10:55:00" "2020/07/07 11:00:00" "2020/07/07 11:05:00" "2020/07/07 11:15:00" ...
  ..$ kcal_hr_M_6: num [1:286] 0.153 0.156 0.163 0.166 0.173 ...
  ..$ VO2_M_6    : num [1:286] 0.527 0.536 0.566 0.571 0.598 ...
  ..$ VCO2_M_6   : num [1:286] 0.438 0.436 0.457 0.48 0.494 ...
  ..$ Sum_6period: num [1:286] 0.963 0.975 0.979 0.982 0.985 ...
  ..$ ..I        : int [1:286] 264 265 266 268 267 263 254 275 253 255 ...
  ..- attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr> 
  ..- attr(*, "index")= int(0) 
  .. ..- attr(*, "__..I")= int [1:286] 250 246 237 234 226 216 210 202 198 183 ...
 $ June7RMRA7       :Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame': 286 obs. of  6 variables:
  ..$ DateTime   : chr [1:286] "2020/07/07 11:10:00" "2020/07/07 11:15:00" "2020/07/07 11:20:00" "2020/07/07 11:05:00" ...
  ..$ kcal_hr_M_7: num [1:286] 0.196 0.228 0.255 0.292 0.257 ...
  ..$ VO2_M_7    : num [1:286] 0.66 0.765 0.856 0.986 0.876 ...
  ..$ VCO2_M_7   : num [1:286] 0.625 0.742 0.831 0.933 0.807 ...
  ..$ Sum_6period: num [1:286] 1.41 1.44 1.5 1.5 1.51 ...
  ..$ ..I        : int [1:286] 267 268 269 266 270 265 271 272 264 263 ...
  ..- attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr> 
  ..- attr(*, "index")= int(0) 
  .. ..- attr(*, "__..I")= int [1:286] 100 117 119 126 133 136 130 113 118 131 ...
 $ June7RMRA8       :Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame': 286 obs. of  6 variables:
  ..$ DateTime   : chr [1:286] "2020/07/07 10:50:00" "2020/07/07 10:55:00" "2020/07/07 10:45:00" "2020/07/07 11:00:00" ...
  ..$ kcal_hr_M_8: num [1:286] 0.2 0.187 0.203 0.18 0.191 ...
  ..$ VO2_M_8    : num [1:286] 0.701 0.656 0.705 0.628 0.664 ...
  ..$ VCO2_M_8   : num [1:286] 0.516 0.494 0.532 0.5 0.529 ...
  ..$ Sum_6period: num [1:286] 1.12 1.12 1.14 1.14 1.15 ...
  ..$ ..I        : int [1:286] 263 264 262 265 266 261 267 260 279 280 ...
  ..- attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr> 
  ..- attr(*, "index")= int(0) 
  .. ..- attr(*, "__..I")= int [1:286] 196 180 165 151 141 135 119 125 117 106 ...
 $ June18RMRA8comp  :Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame': 6 obs. of  6 variables:
  ..$ DateTime   : chr [1:6] "2020/06/19 10:57:00" "2020/06/19 11:02:00" "2020/06/19 11:07:00" "2020/06/19 11:12:00" ...
  ..$ kcal_hr_M_8: num [1:6] 0.152 0.16 0.16 0.169 0.177 ...
  ..$ VO2_M_8    : num [1:6] 0.524 0.553 0.552 0.58 0.606 ...
  ..$ VCO2_M_8   : num [1:6] 0.429 0.454 0.46 0.501 0.53 ...
  ..$ Sum_6period: num [1:6] 0.985 1.015 1.055 1.106 1.125 ...
  ..$ ..I        : int [1:6] 256 257 258 259 260 261
  ..- attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr> 
 $ August25RMRA6comp:Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame': 6 obs. of  6 variables:
  ..$ DateTime   : chr [1:6] "2020/08/26 08:33:00" "2020/08/26 08:38:00" "2020/08/26 08:43:00" "2020/08/26 08:48:00" ...
  ..$ kcal_hr_M_6: num [1:6] 0.257 0.259 0.25 0.253 0.261 ...
  ..$ VO2_M_6    : num [1:6] 0.943 0.954 0.922 0.933 0.952 ...
  ..$ VCO2_M_6   : num [1:6] 0.535 0.521 0.5 0.517 0.557 ...
  ..$ Sum_6period: num [1:6] 1.55 1.57 1.74 1.85 1.9 ...
  ..$ ..I        : int [1:6] 226 227 228 229 230 231
  ..- attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr> 
 $ June1DEEA1       : num 0.307
 $ June1DEEA2       : num 0.356
 $ June1DEEA3       : num 0.377
 $ June1DEEA4       : num 0.37
 $ June1DEEA5       : num 0.356
 $ June1DEEA6       : num 0.407
 $ June1DEEA7       : num 0.307
 $ June1DEEA8       : num 0.387
 $ August19MassA1   : num 24
 $ July27MassA1     : num 18
 $ August19MassA2   : num 20.8
 $ July27MassA2     : num 0
 $ August19MassA3   : num 15.7
 $ July27MassA3     : num 18.2
 $ August19MassA4   : num 21.1
 $ July27MassA4     : num 0
 $ August19MassA5   : num 0
 $ July27MassA5     : num 26.3
 $ August19MassA6   : num 18.4
 $ July27MassA6     : num 16.1
 $ August19MassA7   : num 17.6
 $ July27MassA7     : num 18.3
 $ August12RMRA1    :Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame': 281 obs. of  6 variables:
  ..$ DateTime   : chr [1:281] "2020/08/12 15:04:00" "2020/08/13 08:44:00" "2020/08/13 06:54:00" "2020/08/13 08:39:00" ...
  ..$ kcal_hr_M_1: num [1:281] 0.19 0.216 0.196 0.212 0.217 ...
  ..$ VO2_M_1    : num [1:281] 0.647 0.734 0.669 0.723 0.738 ...
  ..$ VCO2_M_1   : num [1:281] 0.557 0.674 0.595 0.645 0.66 ...
  ..$ Sum_6period: num [1:281] 1.19 1.22 1.23 1.23 1.23 ...
  ..$ ..I        : int [1:281] 1 213 191 212 190 2 214 192 193 194 ...
  ..- attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr> 
  ..- attr(*, "index")= int(0) 
  .. ..- attr(*, "__..I")= int [1:281] 1 6 19 29 48 71 103 127 134 147 ...
 $ August19MassA8   : num 19.8
 $ July27MassA8     : num 16.1
 $ August12RMRA2    :Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame': 281 obs. of  6 variables:
  ..$ DateTime   : chr [1:281] "2020/08/13 00:39:00" "2020/08/13 00:34:00" "2020/08/13 00:29:00" "2020/08/13 00:44:00" ...
  ..$ kcal_hr_M_2: num [1:281] 0.22 0.234 0.217 0.203 0.222 ...
  ..$ VO2_M_2    : num [1:281] 0.745 0.793 0.736 0.683 0.748 ...
  ..$ VCO2_M_2   : num [1:281] 0.697 0.736 0.666 0.651 0.648 ...
  ..$ Sum_6period: num [1:281] 1.22 1.25 1.27 1.27 1.28 ...
  ..$ ..I        : int [1:281] 116 115 114 117 210 211 209 208 113 207 ...
  ..- attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr> 
  ..- attr(*, "index")= int(0) 
  .. ..- attr(*, "__..I")= int [1:281] 62 82 79 76 68 77 97 94 92 98 ...
 $ August12RMRA3    :Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame': 281 obs. of  6 variables:
  ..$ DateTime   : chr [1:281] "2020/08/12 21:44:00" "2020/08/13 09:19:00" "2020/08/13 08:19:00" "2020/08/12 21:49:00" ...
  ..$ kcal_hr_M_3: num [1:281] 0.281 0.277 0.253 0.254 0.283 ...
  ..$ VO2_M_3    : num [1:281] 0.969 0.977 0.896 0.882 0.981 ...
  ..$ VCO2_M_3   : num [1:281] 0.809 0.741 0.655 0.72 0.796 ...
  ..$ Sum_6period: num [1:281] 1.52 1.52 1.52 1.53 1.53 ...
  ..$ ..I        : int [1:281] 81 220 208 82 80 221 219 206 209 205 ...
  ..- attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr> 
  ..- attr(*, "index")= int(0) 
  .. ..- attr(*, "__..I")= int [1:281] 59 65 70 73 88 108 96 100 114 126 ...
 $ August12RMRA4    :Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame': 281 obs. of  6 variables:
  ..$ DateTime   : chr [1:281] "2020/08/13 08:19:00" "2020/08/13 08:24:00" "2020/08/13 01:14:00" "2020/08/13 09:39:00" ...
  ..$ kcal_hr_M_4: num [1:281] 0.207 0.21 0.241 0.209 0.237 ...
  ..$ VO2_M_4    : num [1:281] 0.72 0.726 0.84 0.74 0.809 ...
  ..$ VCO2_M_4   : num [1:281] 0.558 0.567 0.67 0.637 0.699 ...
  ..$ Sum_6period: num [1:281] 1.36 1.38 1.38 1.39 1.39 ...
  ..$ ..I        : int [1:281] 208 209 123 224 223 207 220 210 204 221 ...
  ..- attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr> 
  ..- attr(*, "index")= int(0) 
  .. ..- attr(*, "__..I")= int [1:281] 88 87 95 129 144 159 165 171 168 142 ...
 $ June7RMRA1comp   :Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame': 6 obs. of  6 variables:
  ..$ DateTime   : chr [1:6] "2020/07/07 10:05:00" "2020/07/07 10:10:00" "2020/07/07 10:15:00" "2020/07/07 10:30:00" ...
  ..$ kcal_hr_M_1: num [1:6] 0.216 0.194 0.204 0.211 0.218 ...
  ..$ VO2_M_1    : num [1:6] 0.746 0.663 0.696 0.716 0.741 ...
  ..$ VCO2_M_1   : num [1:6] 0.653 0.592 0.624 0.662 0.678 ...
  ..$ Sum_6period: num [1:6] 1.25 1.29 1.35 1.38 1.38 ...
  ..$ ..I        : int [1:6] 254 255 256 259 257 258
  ..- attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr> 
 $ August12RMRA5    :Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame': 281 obs. of  6 variables:
  ..$ DateTime   : chr [1:281] "2020/08/13 11:14:00" "2020/08/13 09:49:00" "2020/08/13 11:09:00" "2020/08/13 09:44:00" ...
  ..$ kcal_hr_M_5: num [1:281] 0.25 0.237 0.245 0.29 0.264 ...
  ..$ VO2_M_5    : num [1:281] 0.876 0.82 0.845 0.987 0.899 ...
  ..$ VCO2_M_5   : num [1:281] 0.699 0.665 0.713 0.791 0.754 ...
  ..$ Sum_6period: num [1:281] 1.42 1.42 1.44 1.46 1.46 ...
  ..$ ..I        : int [1:281] 243 226 242 225 224 241 244 227 218 219 ...
  ..- attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr> 
  ..- attr(*, "index")= int(0) 
  .. ..- attr(*, "__..I")= int [1:281] 32 50 59 72 109 128 141 130 137 147 ...
 $ August12RMRA6    :Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame': 281 obs. of  6 variables:
  ..$ DateTime   : chr [1:281] "2020/08/13 00:44:00" "2020/08/13 00:39:00" "2020/08/13 09:04:00" "2020/08/13 10:19:00" ...
  ..$ kcal_hr_M_6: num [1:281] 0.276 0.333 0.291 0.286 0.294 ...
  ..$ VO2_M_6    : num [1:281] 0.935 1.14 1.029 0.983 1.028 ...
  ..$ VCO2_M_6   : num [1:281] 0.856 1.028 0.811 0.805 0.797 ...
  ..$ Sum_6period: num [1:281] 1.71 1.72 1.73 1.73 1.73 ...
  ..$ ..I        : int [1:281] 117 116 217 232 218 115 231 219 216 212 ...
  ..- attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr> 
  ..- attr(*, "index")= int(0) 
  .. ..- attr(*, "__..I")= int [1:281] 122 125 123 126 133 132 130 127 124 117 ...
 $ August12RMRA7    :Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame': 281 obs. of  6 variables:
  ..$ DateTime   : chr [1:281] "2020/08/13 08:54:00" "2020/08/13 10:59:00" "2020/08/13 08:59:00" "2020/08/13 09:04:00" ...
  ..$ kcal_hr_M_7: num [1:281] 0.188 0.192 0.182 0.183 0.174 ...
  ..$ VO2_M_7    : num [1:281] 0.661 0.681 0.63 0.626 0.607 ...
  ..$ VCO2_M_7   : num [1:281] 0.516 0.573 0.516 0.521 0.532 ...
  ..$ Sum_6period: num [1:281] 1.13 1.14 1.15 1.15 1.15 ...
  ..$ ..I        : int [1:281] 215 240 216 217 241 239 205 214 198 202 ...
  ..- attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr> 
  ..- attr(*, "index")= int(0) 
  .. ..- attr(*, "__..I")= int [1:281] 210 216 228 222 194 173 156 144 129 102 ...
 $ August12RMRA8    :Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame': 281 obs. of  6 variables:
  ..$ DateTime   : chr [1:281] "2020/08/13 08:09:00" "2020/08/13 08:04:00" "2020/08/13 08:14:00" "2020/08/13 11:14:00" ...
  ..$ kcal_hr_M_8: num [1:281] 0.254 0.298 0.233 0.285 0.319 ...
  ..$ VO2_M_8    : num [1:281] 0.903 1.053 0.829 1.004 1.108 ...
  ..$ VCO2_M_8   : num [1:281] 0.641 0.761 0.59 0.743 0.889 ...
  ..$ Sum_6period: num [1:281] 1.48 1.52 1.52 1.53 1.55 ...
  ..$ ..I        : int [1:281] 206 205 207 243 225 244 242 241 239 240 ...
  ..- attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr> 
  ..- attr(*, "index")= int(0) 
  .. ..- attr(*, "__..I")= int [1:281] 99 110 115 114 109 107 106 92 80 81 ...
 $ June16RMRA5comp  :Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame': 6 obs. of  6 variables:
  ..$ DateTime   : chr [1:6] "2020/06/17 07:37:00" "2020/06/17 07:42:00" "2020/06/17 07:47:00" "2020/06/17 07:52:00" ...
  ..$ kcal_hr_M_5: num [1:6] 0.3 0.285 0.301 0.327 0.319 ...
  ..$ VO2_M_5    : num [1:6] 1.039 0.991 1.041 1.137 1.119 ...
  ..$ VCO2_M_5   : num [1:6] 0.848 0.793 0.864 0.912 0.856 ...
  ..$ Sum_6period: num [1:6] 1.87 1.91 1.96 1.99 2 ...
  ..$ ..I        : int [1:6] 220 221 222 223 224 225
  ..- attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr> 
 $ RMRVO2June18A1   : num 1.03
  [list output truncated]
```

Comment: Why are you saving these in the global environment? Your issue wouldn't even exist if you had followed good practice and put them in a list or dedicated environment when they were created. Anyway, you could do something like `mylist <- Filter(is.numeric, mget(ls(.GlobalEnv)))`

Comment: That worked perfectly, Roland! Thank you! Sorry, I'm pretty new to R and coding in general. How would you recommend saving many values to a list/dedicated environment? Thanks again.

Comment: Instead if `August12MassA1 <- 15.4; August12MassA2 <- 0; ...` you do `MonthMasses <- list(); MonthMasses[["August12MassA1"]] <- 15.4; ...`. If these are always single values, use a named vector instead, i.e., start with `MonthMasses <- numeric()`. There are even better approaches if these values are created in a loop.

Comment: That makes sense! Thank you. I got each value from a formula calculation so it didn't really occur to me to save them in their own list, but I'll make sure to do so in the future, thanks so much! :)